# Split array into smaller parts of defined value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that consists of anywhere between 200-7000 values. I would like to split this array into smaller chunks based on a defined value.

For example:

The array has 1731 values, I want to break it down into smaller arrays with each array only having *50* values per.

How is this done? The part I'm stuck with is getting it to break down into 50 values per.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

https://www.php.net/array_chunk

array_chunk($array, 50) returns an array with each value being an array with 50 values each from $array.

```
//make an array with numbers from 1 to 500
$array = range(1, 500);
//break that array up into chunks of 50.
$newArray = array_chunk($array, 50);
//display the new array
var_dump($newArray);
```

example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/JNzSWO

Comment: Yes, I understand it's done with array_chunk, however I'm not sure how to break it down with 50 values per.

Comment: By passing `50` as the second argument to the function. Did you read the documentation? It clearly demonstrates this.

Comment: @nick there is an example now.

Answer (score 0):

Use the array chunk function:

> Chunks an array into size large chunks. The last chunk may contain less than size elements.

Usage:

```
array array_chunk ( array $input , int $size [, bool $preserve_keys = false ] )
```

Example:

Input:

```
<?php
    $input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
    print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 2));
    print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 2, true));
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
            [1] => d
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => e
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [2] => c
            [3] => d
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [4] => e
        )

)
```

So, if you had an `array` named `$a`, you would use:

```
$components = array_chunk($a, 50, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_chunk()](https://www.php.net/array_chunk)

eg:

```
$array = range(1, 1731);
if(count($array) => 200 || count($array) <= 7000)){
    $split = array_chunk($input_array, 50, true);
} else {
    $split = $array;
}
var_export($split);
```

`$split` will have around 35 arrays if the initial array's counter is over 200 and under 7000